# bootstrap modal loading content via remote url, wait for modal to fully load content until being shown

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

i'm able to load content via a remote url into a bootstrap modal, but the problem is the modal window opens up, but the content is not loaded.

Once the content is loaded the body of the modal is updated and the height expands to fit the content of the modal.

However, i'd like to only display the modal once the content is fully loaded, and maybe display an animated gif while the modal is loading.

I've looked at the docs, but i didn't see anything there about maybe a callback once the modal is loaded. I was hoping to maybe keep the modal hidden until the callback was fired and show it.
how can i do this?

Comment: Don't show the modal until the success callback of the ajax method is executed. http://api.jquery.com/load/#callback-function

Comment: You could do an AJAX call and on the `success`, call the modal with the HTML downloaded with AJAX appended. That should be enough unless it's a form or something that needs submit (because of form's action etc will point to your server, unless it's absolute path).

Comment: thanks guys! i got it with your suggestions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got it thanks to the above comments.  I stored the remote urls for the anchor tags that trigger a popup using a data attribute ('data-href') with the anchors class name as 'popup-links' using the following javascript:

```
$jq191('.popup-links').on( 'click', function( e ){
    var remote= $jq191( this ).data( 'href' );
    $jq191('.modal-body').load( remote, function( e ){
        $jq191( '#myModal' ).modal( 'show' );
    });
});
```