# Load remote url to Bootstrap Modal via script

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Samples that show how to inject remote html to a Bootstrap's (2x) modal-body always depend on the href property of an `<a>` tag. I need to trigger the modal ('show' *and* fire the remote call for it's body) via script instead.

Not this:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="remote.html" data-target="#modal">click me</a>
```

Need this:

```
$("#myModalBtn").on('click', function () {//how do I specify 'remote.html' here?});
```

Comment: I think the answer will be something inspired by this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16531234/bootstrap-modal-loading-content-via-remote-url-wait-for-modal-to-fully-load-con?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Try

give an id to `a` tag like below .

```
<a data-toggle="modal" id="modal_a" data-target="#modal">click me</a>
```

**js**

```
$("#myModalBtn").on('click', function () {
   $('#modal_a').prop('href','remote.html').click();//assign href attribute and click it
});
```

Comment: You've copied my 'Not Like This' specification. I can't use an anchor - i'm being forced to use <button> hmmm...  i wonder if i can wrap an anchor in a button.

Comment: @justSteve yes you can wrap `<a href=""><button></a>`